# how to include a php file from a folder

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to work with the include statement in php by including a php file where the footer is supposed to be. Yet, I am getting error messages saying
**"include(includes/footer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in "**

OR

**"Warning: include(): Failed opening 'includes/footer.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') "** . I don't know if I am missing something or do I need to do something else when retrieving a file from a different folder? Here is code

include.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>
  <title>include</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .foot-item{width:33.33% min-height:120px; border-right:solid 1px white; }
  .foot-item:nth-last-child{ border-right:none;}
  .foot-item h3 a{color:#0099ff; text-decoration:none;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="contain">
    <article>
      <header><h1>include</h1></header>
      <section>
        <blockquote>The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file. </blockquote>
          <p>Default</p>
            <div id="result">Result</div>
            <?php

            ?>
          </section>

        </article>
      <?php  include('includes/footer.php');?>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

includes/footer.php

```
<footer>
  <div class="foot-item">
    <h3><a href="#">Recent Posts</a></h3>
    <ul><li>link<li><li>link<li><li>link<li></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="foot-item">
      <h3><a href="#">Free Newsletters</a></h3>
      <ul><li>link<li><li>link<li><li>link<li></ul>
      </div>
      <div class="foot-item">
        <h3><a href="#">Social Links</a></h3>
        <ul><li>link<li><li>link<li><li>link<li></ul>
        </div>
      </footer>
```

Comment: So your files are stored in something like this : `path/to/webroot/include.php` and `path/to/webroot/includes/footer.php`?

Comment: Try include(\_\_DIR\_\_ . '/includes/footer.php');

Comment: Ahh fxing markdown.

Comment: @Terminus the path to my file is this C:/wamp/www/PHP%20Lynda/PHP%20reference/include.php

Comment: What you have here is correct, so its unlikely that you've posted all the code. Could something be changing your current working directory during the runtime (chdir in php)? Either way, `include(__DIR__ . '/includes/footer.php');` should fix it.

Comment: @rjdown I have done that, and I still get an error

Comment: and what's the exact path to the `footer.php` file?

Comment: "and what's the exact path to the footer.php file?" C:/wamp/www/PHP%20Lynda/PHP%20reference/%20includes/footer.php

Comment: where are those `%20`'s coming from? Does your `includes` folder have a space in its name?

Comment: @Terminus when I posted path to the includes file. I realized that the includes name had a 20% right beside it so I added a space in the include string and it worked. I didn't realized there was a space initially in the folder that I created

Comment: i'd recommend removing the space from the folder name instead of adding the space to your code. Save yourself from having to add the space everytime.

Answer (score 1):

If your file structure is:

```
include.php
includes/
    footer.php
```

you can use:

```
<?php include('./includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

if file structure is different, write relative or absolute path to target file. For example if file structure:

```
code/
    include.php
includes/
    footer.php
```

you can write:

```
<?php include('../includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

P.S. '../' is folder up, './' is current folder, '../../' is two folder up.

Good luck!